# VectorLayer not showing with OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm basically trying to reproduce the [center example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/center.html) in my own [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p14chu5z/)

```
const geoJSON = {};

const features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geoJSON);
const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: features,
});
const style = new ol.style.Style({});
const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: style,
});

let olView = new ol.View({
  center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([6.6339863, 46.5193823]),
  zoom: 4,
});

let olLayers = [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM(),
  }),
  vectorLayer
];

new ol.Map({
  layers: olLayers,
  view: olView,
  target: 'app',
});
```

I must be missing somethig obvious, as the vector layer isn't showing in my fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pan down you will see the vector for Switzerland is in the wrong place

[image]

If using `readFeatures` you need to specify the feature projection so the geojson Lon/Lat coordinates are transformed to view projection

```
const features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geoJSON, {featureProjection: olView.getProjection()});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/apowe4gj/

Comment: Thanks Mike! I knew it would be something obvious.